# Error sending email with Java Commons Mail

Tags: java, email

Good morning! I have searched a lot here to find a solution, but everything I found didn't work.
I have the class Mail:

```
package model.mail;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;

public class Mail extends MultiPartEmail {

    // Default constructor
    public Mail() throws EmailException {

        this( null, null, null, null);

    }

    // My Constructor
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Mail( String receiver, String subject, String message, EmailAttachment[] attachments ) throws EmailException {

        this.addTo( receiver, "" );

        this.setSubject( new String( subject.getBytes( Charset.forName("utf-8") ), Charset.forName("utf-8") ) );

        this.setMsg( new String( message.getBytes( Charset.forName("utf-8") ), Charset.forName("utf-8") ) );

        if( attachments != null ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++ )
                this.attach( attachments[i] );
        }

        this.setSSL(true);

    }

}
```

And the Main class:

```
package main;

import model.mail.Mail;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Mail email = new Mail( "user@domain.com", "Teste", "teste..", null );
            email.setHostName( "smtp.mail.yahoo.com" );
            email.setSmtpPort( 587 );
            email.setAuthentication( "user@yahoo.com.br", "mypassword" );
            email.setFrom( "user@yahoo.com.br", "My Name" );
            email.send();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This code used to work, but it's not working anymore. When I run it, I get this exception:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, 465; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:367)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:295)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:208)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 9 more
```

Please, forgive-me if I did some mistakes, I am new here.

UPDATED: I finally found the error! Probably, the mail server changed and now it requires TLS authentication. I changed the authentication to TLS and it worked!

Comment: Can you send mail through the same server using a normal e-mail client and similar parameters?

Comment: No, I can't. I also tried to chage the server, but nothing worked.

Comment: @LucasMP Sounds like a networking / mail server issue. Probably off-topic for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree that it looks like a network/server issue. In order to test and debug your Java code, you need a combination of server and parameters that will let you send e-mail using a well-tested mail client.

Comment: @Duncan But what could be? The code used to work and my network configuration is the same. I checked the firewall, antivirus...

Comment: @LucasMP Sorry, I'm not an expert on that subject. I just know that your Java code is not at fault.

Comment: @LucasMP Servers change. Networks change. Your Java code didn't change. That strongly suggests you should not be looking for the problem in the Java code.

Comment: A quick Google search suggests Yahoo's SMTP port is 465, although I'm not sure why your code used to work before.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys! I'll look at my network and I'll try to test it in another network.

Comment: @Ray I searched and I saw that to send email with SSL authentication, the port should be 587.
PS: The code also didn't work with 465 port.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting port 587, but then in the method is enabled SSL(465)

```
this.setSSL(true);
```

Your firewall may be blocking port 465. Try to remove that piece of code and use for real port 587 and see if it works. If so, you have to contact your network administrator or struggle with network configuration.

Comment: It doesn't work, because the server requires SSL authentication.

Comment: The line that sets the post should use the setSslSmtpPort(587) instead since SSL will be enabled. Also, setSSL is deprecated, so in the future you will need to use setSSLOnConnect.